# Loop through an array list to make a post request for a rest API dynamic

Tags: javascript, rest, axios

I update an object. This object is an array which can have a length from one to five. This is my object `["max", "dog"]`.

Now a post method is to be called. It is so if the user has only 2 things filled in, only two things should be sent there. If 5 then 5 (see example for a better explanation.) Does anyone have an idea how best to set this up?

```
const tag = ["max", "dog"]
const updateInterest = () => {
    axios
      .post("...", {
        first1: max,
        first2: dog,
        // first3: ...,
        // first4: ...,
        // first4: ...,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          // API update interest
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

What I try

```
const tag = ["max", "dog"]
const updateInterest = () => {
    const object = "";
    tags.map((tag, index) =>{
      console.log(tag + " " + index)
      object = 
        `first${index}`: `${tag}`,
      
  })
    axios
      .post("...", {
        object
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          // API update interest
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

My loop doesn't really make much sense. How can I add this to an object so that it can be sent in later in an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.fromEntries()` to map an array of arrays to object, like in the following example:

```js
const arr = ["max", "dog"];

const mapped = arr.map((el, i) => [`first${i+1}`, el]);


console.log(Object.fromEntries(mapped))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to achieve the same thing:

```js
const arr = ['cat', 'dog'];

const obj = arr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => ((acc[`first${i + 1}`] = cur), acc), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Reference: [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215753/11613622)