# How to convert array to an object with key/value pairs Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a configurable checkbox and want to have my array's values to be the keys for the object.

Given:

```
let colors = [red, blue, black, yellow, orange]
```

How do I make it so that it becomes:

```
colorChecklist = {
    red: true,
    blue: true,
    black: true,
    yellow: true,
    orange: true
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: @TBA That's way different than this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here .

**One-liner**

```
const colorChecklist = colors.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr] = true, acc), {});
```

```js
let colors = ["red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "orange"];

const colorChecklist = colors.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = true;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(colorChecklist);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const obj = {};
colors.forEach(c => obj[c] = true)
```

I know everybody likes reduce but it's unnecessarily complicated and well, see [this](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
const [red, blue, black, yellow, orange] = ["red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "orange"]

let colors = [red, blue, black, yellow, orange];

let colorChecklist = colors.reduce((acc, key) => (acc[key] = true, acc), {});

console.log(colorChecklist);
```

Comment: @FZs OP used identifiers in the creation of the `colors` array, not strings, so I did the same

Comment: I see now. I overlooked that thinking the OP meant strings, but forgot to add the quotes because of inexperience or lack of attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a mass assignment (using an object method) to all of the properties since they are all boolean in type.

```
let colors = [true, true, true] // red, blue, green

var colorChecklist = {
    setValue: function( props, flag ) {
        while ( props.length ) this[ props.pop() ] = flag;
    }
}

colorChecklist.setValue( [...colors] , true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```js
const colorChecklist = colors.reduce((prev, curr) => ({ ...prev, [curr]: true }), {});
console.log(colorChecklist);
```

Answer (score -1):

try with Array#Reduce

```
const arr = ['a','b','c'];
const res = arr.reduce((acc,curr)=> (acc[curr]='',acc),{});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: This sets each value to an empty string, not `true`

Comment: @Samathingamajig I have just given an example of how you can use array Reduce, you can always configure the value the way you want.