# How to insert object inside an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to insert an object inside another object and with what I tried I wasn't successful in any of the, let's say I want to insert an object inside an object, these are the ways I tried:

```
var ob = {
 user1: {name: 'chris'}
};

1:
ob['user2']['name'] = 'Luana'; //error

2:
var obA = ob['user2'];
obA['name'] = 'Luana'; //error

3:
ob['user2'] = ['name'] = 'Luana'; //error
```

These are the ways I tried, but since I am not successful, how can I insert other properties, other than this way below?

`obA['user2'] = {name: 'Luana'}; // for me this is not what i'm looking for`

**My wish is to make the code below:**

```
var gentleman = {};
var test = 0;

onclick = () => {
 test = 1;

 gentleman ['names'] [test] = 'I am a gentleman' test
 
 console.log (gentleman);
}
```

**Return this result:**

```
gentleman = {
 names: {
   1: 'Im gentleman 1',
   2: 'Im gentleman 2',
   3: 'Im gentleman 3',
   ...
 }
}
```

**Note**
What I'm doing is, create a piano and each key prepreced I create a new audio with `new Audio` and pass the url of this key itself, so far so good, the problem needs some logic to check if the audio is already was called, the logic I thought was the following:
When the user clicks on the key I insert into a `notes_` object the property with the key of the `C or D ...` key is the value of the `new Audio` audio, each key I insert into this same `notes_` object that is inside another `songs_` object. As I saw in several answers, when adding as mentioned in them, the values ​​that are in the object are reset, but that's not what I want;

**Check it out**

```
var songs_ = {
 music1 = 'name',
 music2 = 'name',
 notes_ = {}
};
```

Each key I press, I'll add a property to notes_ like this:

```
var key_ = new audio(urlNote);

note 1 C = key_;

notes_ = {
 C = key_, //(here contains the audio of the note itself C)
 C_ = key_,
 D = key_,
 ...
} // the content here should not be changed, just added
```

Comment: `obA['user2'] = {name: 'Luana'};`  is not what you are looking for? Why not if that is how it works

Comment: var ob = {
 user1: {name: 'chris'}
};


ob = {
  ...ob,
  user2: {name: 'Luag'}
}
console.log(ob)

Comment: Key in the object `ob` is `user1` but you are trying to use `user2` which is undefined. This is why "1" and "2" don't work.

Comment: I rephrased the question to make it a little clearer, sorry

Comment: So I think you are searching for something like .push() but for Objects right? You could do it as Array and convert it into objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Comment: @ChrisAnswood - You still haven't answered mplungjan's question. Currently, the question seems to boil-down to "I know how to do it, but I don't feel like doing it this way. Can someone help me find an alternative?" - which, without any justification sounds misguided at best.

Answer (score 1):

Update after updated question

```js
var gentleman = { names:{}};
var test = 0;
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
 test++
 gentleman ['names'] [test] = `I am a gentleman ${test}`
 console.log (gentleman);
})
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Click</button>
```

Old answer:

> the key I'm trying to enter is a variable eg: `var key = 'user'; var keyI = 'name'; ob[key][keyI] = 'name'`

Perhaps you meant this?

```js
var obj = {
  user1: {
    name: 'chris'
  }
};
console.log(obj)

let key = 'somekey'
let key1 = 'someotherkey'
let val = 'somevalue'
obj[key] = {[key1] : val}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I rephrased the question to make it a little clearer, sorry

Comment: @ChrisAnswood See update.

Answer (score 0):

There is another regularly way.

You could try this:

```js
var ob = {
 user1: {name: 'chris'}
};

var ob2 =  {
 user2: {name: 'Luana'}
};
var result = Object.assign(ob, ob2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I rephrased the question to make it a little clearer, sorry

Answer (score -1):

Not possible in that way.

```
var ob = {
 user1: {name: 'chris'}
};

//If you wanna do this, it will show you an error since 'user2' does not exists on ob:
ob['user2']['name'] = 'Luana'

// So yo wanna create it first:
ob['user2'] = {name: 'chris'};
```

Comment: I rephrased the question to make it a little clearer, sorry