# How i can to convert array to object of array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data in array

```
["Avengers","Batman","Spiderman","IronMan"]
```

how I can to covert to below

```
{"Avenger":"Avenger","Batmane":"Batman","Spiderman":"Spiderman","Ironman":"Ironman"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
let arr = ["Avengers","Batman","Spiderman","IronMan"];
let obj = arr.reduce((acc, item)=> ({...acc, [item]: item}) , {});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone else mentioned reduce, but I recommend against, copying objects at every iteration.

Here's a more performant approach.

```js
const arr = ["Avengers","Batman","Spiderman","IronMan"];
const obj = {};

for (const el of arr) {
  obj[el] = el;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use reduce to convert array to object.
You can see some examples in here [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)