# Constructing raw data out of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, postman

I need to construct API body for using in **javascript fetch**. The length of array is twenty or so and I need a loop.

I have an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        name:"x",lname:"y"
    },
    {
        name:"x2",lname:"y2"
    },
]
```

and this what I want to achieve:

```
{
    "0":{
        "name":"x",
        "lname":"y"
    },
    "1":{
        "name":"x2",
        "lname":"y2"
    },
}
```

This is raw in postman body:

[image]

Any guide and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you want to convert an array to an object. I'm not sure how Postman is relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: I added an image from postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting an Array to an Object is easily done with `Array.reduce` and using the `index` argument as the key of the properties:

```js
const data = [
    {name:"x",lname:"y"},
    {name:"x2",lname:"y2"},
]

console.log( 
  data.reduce((acc, item, i) => ({...acc, [i]:item}) ,{})
)
```

Or shorter, as suggested by `@CherryDT` (in the comments below), which automatically converts the Array to an Object consisting of keys derived from the array's items' indices:

```js
const data = [
    {name:"x",lname:"y"},
    {name:"x2",lname:"y2"},
]

console.log({...data})
```

Tip: If you want the keys indices to start from `1` and not `0`, do:

```
console.log({...[,...data]})
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this a better answer. ES6 syntax isn't exactly intuitive.

Comment: I want the keys to be in string format. For example "1":{}

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex - `{...array}` would do the same-

Comment: @SeyedMahdiJalali That's what this code does... but if you are referring to quotes: they are not part of the object, they are part of the JSON representation. To get a JSON string from an object you can use `JSON.stringify`, but depending on which request library you use, you don't even have to worry about that.

Comment: @SeyedMahdiJalali - the output is exactly as you want. Have you clicked the `run code snippet` button?

Comment: @CherryDT - Correct. Will also update the answer to include that shortcut available by the language syntax