# javascript array to object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

how can i convert elements in array as objects in array?

```html
"allowed_vehicle_types": [
        "A1",
        "A2",
        "A",
        "B1",
]
```

How can I get this array into this shape? this is what i want

```html
[
    { value: 'A1', label: 'A1' },
    { value: 'A2', label: 'A2' },
    { value: 'A', label: 'A' },
    { value: 'B1', label: 'B1' },
]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: @0stone0 That is not a good dupe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `map` on the array and `return` an object with `value` and `label` properties.

```js
const data =  [
        "A1",
        "A2",
        "A",
        "B1",
]

const result = data.map(i => ({ value: i, label: i }));

console.log(result)
```