# marking dates does not work in the calendar

Tags: javascript, php, typescript, react-native, expo

I have a problem developing a calendar where it marks events on the appropriate dates, I receive the dates in the following way in PHP

```
[
  {
    "status": "OK",
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusMensagem": "Listado com sucesso!",
    "arrayDados": [
      {
        "data": "2024-01-17",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-17",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-17",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-24",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-19",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-18",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-19",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-19",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-23",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-24",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-24",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-26",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "2024-01-27",
        "dadosDoDia": {
          "selected": true,
          "marked": true,
          "selectedColor": "blue"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ondeEstou": [],
    "proximos": []
  }
]
```

the code in the calendar is as follows:

```
<Calendar
                  style={[Styles.w95,{
                    borderTopLeftRadius:0,borderTopRightRadius:0,
                    borderBottomLeftRadius:20,borderBottomRightRadius:20,
                    marginTop:'2%',
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    borderColor: 'gray',
                    height: 350,
                    borderRadius:4,
                  }]}
                  current={new Date().toDateString()}
                  onDayPress={day => {
                    
                  }}
                  markedDates={agenda}
                />
```

when I put markedDates like this:

```
markedDates={{
    '2012-03-01': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'},
    '2012-03-02': {marked: true},
    '2012-03-03': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'}
  }}
```

so it marks the dates correctly, but when it returns from the database it does not mark it and the following message appears.
**Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `markedDates` of type `array` supplied to `Calendar`, expected `object`.
at Calendar (http://192.168.1.7:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:223709:28)**

could someone help me please

I can't solve it, I need him to mark the dates like this

Comment: You posted the warning message is *"Invalid prop `markedDates` of type array supplied to Calendar, expected object"*. Your `arrayDados` entries are an array. It expects an object, just as the warning states. Convert it to an object, for example.

Comment: I'm new to javascript is there a function that can help me receive the data in an array and convert it to an object? or any function in php that does this?

Comment: Yes you can even search StackOverflow for [convert javascript array to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object). One of the answers is about the EcmaScript6 way of doing this.

Comment: Voting for duplicate since you're asking for the same thing: [How to convert an array into an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `markedDates` prop requires dates to be formatted in a specific way. For example:

```
markedDates={{
    '2012-03-01': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'},
    '2012-03-02': {marked: true},
    '2012-03-03': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'}
  }}
```

The data you're receiving from the server isn't in the correct format. To ensure the calendar works, you'll need to convert your server-side dates into the required format.

```
const serverResponse = [{
  "status": "OK",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusMensagem": "Listado com sucesso!",
  "arrayDados": [
    {
      "data": "2024-01-17",
      "dadosDoDia": {
        "selected": true,
        "marked": true,
        "selectedColor": "blue"
      }
    },
    {
      "data": "2024-01-18",
      "dadosDoDia": {
        "selected": true,
        "marked": true,
        "selectedColor": "green"
      }
    },
    {
      "data": "2024-01-19",
      "dadosDoDia": {
        "selected": true,
        "marked": true,
        "selectedColor": "red"
      }
    },
    // Assuming more dates follow...
  ]
}];

const convertToMarkedDates = (dataArray) => {
  const markedDates = {};
  dataArray.forEach(item => {
    markedDates[item.data] = item.dadosDoDia;
  });
  return markedDates;
};

const markedDates = convertToMarkedDates(serverResponse[0].arrayDados);
console.log(markedDates); //use this data in your calendar
```

Comment: Great show friend, thank you very much for your help. Worked perfectly.